# Best place to call MiniDumpWriteDump() to catch a crash

Tags: c++, windows, exception, signals, structured-exception

I have a large-ish Win32 program that I'm maintaining, and I'd like to instrument it to automatically and unconditionally generate a minidump file whenever *something bad happens*. I can't ask customers to install userdump.exe, and I can't ask them to install visual studio.

Is there a good way of doing this? I'd like to be able to generate a minidump whether abort() is called from our assert handler (which is complicated), whether someone touches bad memory, or anything else really bad happens.

On Posix, I'd install a signal handler and be done with this. My understanding is that the equivalent approach on Windows is SEH, but our program starts up a lot of threads in a lot of different places so it would be very painful to wrap every thread entry point with a __try/__catch.

Ideas?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! Post this as an answer and I'll add the green check mark.

Comment: `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` does not catch things as an `abort`, which happens on MSVC when you call a mutex in a invalid state. For an alternative, see: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207464/Exception-Handling-in-Visual-Cplusplus

Answer (score 1):

There are [google breakpad](https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad/) client and server components  for catching crashes. You could use this lib

Also you could register your filter(could check for different expedition types ) callback for handling exceptions using  [AddVectoredExceptionHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679274(v=vs.85).aspx).

I hope it helped